# Can i run Python PHP and Java sites on one VPS server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, python

I have one VPS server with cpanel/whm installed. i want to host one python/django and one J2EE based website on that server. is it possible.

I know that i have run thoseweb server at different ports but can users still see the site by typing `http://www.java.com` rather than http://www.java.com:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily have mod_php and mod_wsgi (for python) running on the same apache install and then proxy pass requests for java to port 8080 which like tomcat/jboss will run on.

Should be no problems. You just want to make sure your ram is enough for your services that will run

Comment: I have 1GB RAM on VPS , is that enough for that

Comment: really depends on your traffic and what memory footprint your app(s) use

Comment: I don't have any high traffic sites , just20-30 visits per month. applications  are just personal

Comment: J2EE applications are high memory users, I would be careful as 1gb may not be enough for both applications to run well.